# Getting Error "Failed to find a DNS-record for the resource at" while executing my first testcafe script

Tags: testcafe

I am learning test cafe, written below sample code and executed. It is not working, I am getting error message "Failed to find a DNS-record for the resource". Please guide me what setting I need to do

import {Selector} from 'testcafe';
import {fixture,test,page} from 'testcafe';

fixture `getting started`.page `https://www.google.com1`
;
test('my test1', async (t) => {
await t
.wait(3000)
;
});

Comment: Hi and welcome. Please see this post to edit your question so the community can answer https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there is a typo in the page option. The `google.com1` website is not accessible with a browser.

Please use the following code:

```
fixture `getting started`
    .page `https://www.google.com`;

test('my test1', async t => {
    await t.wait(3000);
});
```